# Как подтянуть новую страницу php html

Tags: php, html

```
// index.php
<html>
 <form action="controller.php"   method="post">
        <button name="page" value="aspirant"  >Соискатель</button>
        <button name="page" value="employer">Работадатель</button>
    </form>';
</html>

//controller.php

<?php

if (!empty($_POST['page'])){
include "/" . $_POST['page'] . ".php"
}
```

После нажатие кнопки подтягивается страница соответствующая нажатой кнопке.
   Проблема в том, что подтягивается страница  туда же, где и расположены кнопки.
А нужно,что-бы  открылась отдельная страница, а не  сверху вызванной.(не вкладка,а страница)

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST['page'])) { header("Location: /" . $_POST['page'] . ".php"); }`

Comment: Но как правильно замечено: " а почему не использовать просто ссылки?"

Comment: Я в программирование новичок, Буду благодарен если подскажите как использовать кнопку-ссылку.

Comment: @Ильдар Всё достаточно просто, вместо тега `<button>` вставьте тег `<a href="http://example.com/path/to/page.php"`. Где `path/to/page.php` - собственно адрес страницы, на которую нужно переходить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то самый простой вариант это редирект:

```
if (!empty($_POST['page'])) {
    print_r('
        <script type="text/javascript">
            location="/'.$_POST['page'].'.php";
        </script>
    ');
}
```

Но для чего в данном случае нужна именно форма и POST-запрос не совсем понимаю. Достаточно обычных ссылок.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, у вас есть два пути решения проблемы: 
1) Заменить форму и `button`-ы на ссылки. Тогда при нажатии на ссылку вы будете переходить на нужную страницу.
2) Отлавливать нажатие по кнопке,с помощью `js` отменять дефолтное действие (`event.preventDefault`) и с помощью `window.location.href = 'url'` перенаправлять юзера на нужную страницу. Если необходимо получать с сервера адрес страницы - делайте `ajax` запрос и в `success` выполняйте перенаправление.